Not unique database value! error in AnyLogic
I have a database with two rows and three columns as follows:
|time                |product|quantity
| 16-04-2024 11:41:14| A  |3
| 16-04-2024 12:41:14| B  |7
What I am trying to do is to use this db for arrival schedule of "source" block in AnyLogic. The issue is with the quantity column.. when I activate "Multiple agents per arrival" option, I get this error:"Not unique database value!". I appreciate it if someone can help me with that.

If I do not activate "Multiple agents per arrival"  option, the model works without any error. It just creates one agent per row.

You need to add a choice condition, AnyLogic does not know which row's quantity  you want to use.
(Think about it: AL wants to know "how many agents per arrival should I create?" and you tell it "whatever is in the quantity column". But there are several values in that column, so which one is it? :) )

I used this query for "Agent per arrival" and it worked.
self.databaseTable.getValue( "quantity", int.class )

